Is there a way to use rsync as default instead of cp when copying in nautilus?
I think rsync is a better program to copy than cp, it would be nice if that or even something more advanced, could be used as plugin in nautilus (or nemo?).
Is there a way to use rsync as default instead of cp when copying in nautilus?
Yes I know grsync.

is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/arneko/NemoRsync

Sounds like the perfect time to dive in the source code to learn how things currently work.

No, there is no way to have nautilus use rsync instead. Nautilus does not use cp, but instead uses its own internal system calls to manipulate files. Changing that core behavior requires changing source code.
You can consider using nautilus scripts to call scripts that invoke rsync from within nautilus, but that is as far as it will go.
